# How to get the total runs of each player and add it to an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, dreamweaver

```
$sum = 0;
$sqlM = "SELECT * FROM players";
$resM = mysql_query($sqlM) or die(mysql_error());
while($rowM = mysql_fetch_array($resM)){
//Total Runs
    $sqlr = "SELECT * FROM runs WHERE pId = ".$rowM['Id']."";
    $resr = mysql_query($sqlr) or die(mysql_error());
    while($rowr = mysql_fetch_array($resr)){
        $sum += $rowr['runs'];
    }
    $totalRuns[$rowr['pId']] = array(
         array( 
        'id' => intval($rowr['pId']),
        'score' => $sum
        )
    );


};
```

How to get all the total runs from each player and add them to an array for sorting purposes? 
There are 2 tables players and runs so for each player i need his total runs and add it into an array so i can get the best 5 run scorers . i tried everything i know but i didn't get it right.
The above code is what i did so far but it is not working.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: can you order it a little more readable?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I guess you can let MySQL do the work for you using a `JOIN`, a `COUNT()` and possibly a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: after adding the sum to `$totalRuns` set $sum to 0 ?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that where you set the value for `$totalRuns[$rowr['pId']]`?

Comment: There are 2 tables players and runs so for each player i need his total runs and add it into an array so i can get the best 5 run scorers . i tried evreything i know but i didnt get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT players.id, COUNT(runs.pId) as runCount
FROM players
JOIN runs ON runs.pId = players.id
GROUP BY players.id
ORDER BY runCount DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Haven't tried it, so there might be a syntax error in it, if so, please post it in a comment so I can fix it.

EDIT: (possible) syntax error fix

Answer (score 0):

Why not just creating another array like so ?

```
$player;
$totolarun;
$player_total=array();

$sum = 0;
$sqlM = "SELECT * FROM players";
$resM = mysql_query($sqlM) or die(mysql_error());
while($rowM = mysql_fetch_array($resM)){
//Total Runs
        $sqlr = "SELECT * FROM runs WHERE pId = ".$rowM['Id']."";
        $resr = mysql_query($sqlr) or die(mysql_error());
        while($rowr = mysql_fetch_array($resr)){
                $sum += $rowr['runs'];
                $totolarun=$sum;
        }
        $player = $rowr['pId'];
        $player_total[$player]= $totolarun;

};
foreach($player_total as $key=>$value){
echo $key ." = ".$value." <br>"; 
}

var_dump($player_total);
```

Hope it gives You an idea. Small Edit here ;O

Comment: Although I'm happy you got your code working, I still believe your counting isn't necessary as MySQL can do it for you. Have you tried executing the query I suggested below, possibly in phpmyadmin or similar tools? In any case, please accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Well i am a beginner in PHP and MySQL this is for a assignment for me. This is the part i got stuck for couple of days